# Решить задачу про циклы и массивы в python

Tags: python, массивы, циклы

Напишите программу, вычисляющую сумму n последовательных чисел.
(начало интервала и n вводятся пользователем). Например, если начало интервала равно 3 и n=4, то программа считает
3+4+5+6=18

```
n = int(input("сколько раз: "))
начало = int(input("начало: "))

for n in range(0, n):
    for i in range(начало):
        i = начало + 1

print(i)
```

Почему этот код не работает?

Comment: 2 цикл зачем?  да и переменная на руском прям глаз режет

Comment: Вообще, это можно решить без циклов. [Пример](https://qna.habr.com/q/99157)

Comment: `print(sum(range(start, start+n+1)))`

Answer (score 2):

Почему код не работет легко разобраться самостоятельно, пройдя по нему шаг за шагом и записывая в столбик значения каждой переменной на каждом шаге.

Задача решается вообще без всяких циклов одной единственной формулой:

```
s = int((2 * start + n - 1) * n / 2) # int() чтоб было целое число
```

или

```
s = (2*start + n - 1) * n // 2 # целочисленное деление, int() не требуется
```

Comment: как-то int смущает  - зачем он?

Comment: а без него будет 18.0 например. МОжно целочисленное деление применить, если смущает :)

Comment: так поставьте // - целочисленное деление

Comment: Просто, чтоб не думалось про какие-то округления :)

Comment: ну да, я про целочисленное деление вообще забыл. Редко используется :)

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```
n = int(input("сколько раз: "))
начало = int(input("начало: "))
сумма = 0

for i in range(начало, начало + n):
    сумма = сумма + i

print(сумма)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input("сколько раз: "))
start = int(input("начало: "))

# Заполняем список необходимыми значениями и вычисляем сумму всего списка
print(sum([i for i in range(start, start + n)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правельно понял:

```
n = int(input("How many counts: ")) #кол-во повторений
start = int(input("Start: ")) #старт
sum = 0 

for i in range(start, start + n): 
    sum += i 
print(sum)
```